# How to get the total amount of hard links in a Linux folder structure?

Tags: linux, hardlink

I am currently having a bit trouble with calculating backup sizes with Jungledisk due to the fact that each hard links seems to be counted as a seperate file. I want to be able to retrieve a list of all hard links in a certain folder structure, in this case everything in /var/ and deeper.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: If your backup software doesn't understand hardlinked files, it isn't really doing a backup of your computer -- when you restore from one of these backups your filesystem will be a total mess and nothing like what you backed up.

Comment: Jungledisk handles hard links pretty well, actually. They are just counted as seperate bytes during creating of the backup. WHen the backup is uploaded to the cloud, the bytes are joined, however, so it does not actually cause a storage problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure exactly what your question is,

If you want to find out how much space is in /var, and it's not a separate partition, then

```
du -hs /var
```

would seem to be your best bet.

If you just want a list of files with more than link, then

```
find /var -type f -nlink +1 -print
```

would do it.